# What can I use in java instead of run function in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I try to convert code Kotlin to java and I could not find run function in java. This is Kotlin code :

```
private val resumeArElementsTask = Runnable {
    locationScene?.resume()
    arSceneView!!.resume()
}
```

And I use resumeArElementsTask like

```
resumeArElementsTask.run {
            computeNewScaleModifierBasedOnDistance(locationMarker, locationNode.distance)
        }
```

When I convert to java

```
private final Runnable resumeArElementsTask = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        locationScene.resume();
        try {
            arSceneView.resume();
        } catch (CameraNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};
```

How can I use run function in java and convert this code to java

```
 resumeArElementsTask.run {
            computeNewScaleModifierBasedOnDistance(locationMarker, locationNode.distance)
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: It's called a trailing lambda. You can pass a normal lambda in instead

Comment: @user202729 `Runnable#run` does not expect a lambda expression. In here, it is about Kotlin's run() extension function.

Comment: Honestly, I doubt you invoke this Runnable even in the Kotlin code. You probably invoke `run()` scoping function, not `run()` function of the Runnable. Runnable remains not at all executed. What do you try to achieve here, why do you pass a block of code into existing runnable?

Comment: `run` basically makes the thing you're calling it on `this` in the scope of the function block you're providing (and returns any value the block evaluates to). Since your `resumeArElementsTask` object doesn't have any fields, `locationMarker` and `locationNode` must be visible in the calling scope. It doesn't have a `computeNewScaleModifierBasedOnDistance` method either, so that must be visible in the calling scope as well. So from what you've posted, you don't need the `run` at all, you can just call what's inside the lambda as-is

Comment: The Kotlin code doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Java code is exactly equivalent to what your Kotlin code *actually* does:

```
computeNewScaleModifierBasedOnDistance(locationMarker, locationNode.getDistance());
```

Note that it doesn't resume anything.  Your Kotlin code doesn't, either.  It looks like it does, but it doesn't.

It sounds like you just want to write

```
runnable.run();
computeNewScaleModifierBasedOnDistance(locationMarker, locationNode.getDistance());
```